# How compact can a thin shell be without collapsing?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, stability

I've heard of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchdahl%27s_theorem.
It states that as the ratio between a spheres radius a it's Schwarzschild radius approaches $9/8$. the pressure at the center tends to infinity.
But what about a shell of matter?
Take a thin shell of matter, with thinckness small compared to it's radius. How small can $R/Rs$ be before it must collapse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thin shell could be even more compact than the fluid ball of the same mass. Assuming reasonable energy conditions on the shell matter, the minimal radius of a shell with mass $M$ is:
$$ R_\text{min}=\frac{25}{12} M=\frac{25}{24} \,r_s .$$

This result could be found here:

- Frauendiener, J., Hoenselaers, C., & Konrad, W. (1990). *A shell around a black hole*, Classical and Quantum Gravity, 7(4), 585, [doi:10.1088/0264-9381/7/4/011](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/7/4/011), [free pdf](https://homepages.uni-tuebingen.de//wilfried.konrad/seiten/shell_around.pdf).

Also considered in this paper is the shell around the black hole, or by Birkhoff's theorem around any spherically symmetric distribution of matter more compact than the shell, such as those proposed in OP's [another question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/709450/180269).

Comment: That's a lot smaller then I thought it would be.

Comment: @A.V.S. Could you please clarify how exactly the given $R_{min}$ is defined?  Is it a reduced circumference of the shell, as observed from outside, or is it the radial distance to the center, as measured on the inside? I believe these two definitions do not match (please correct me if I am wrong), because the spatial component of the metric is not continuous through an infinitely thin shell (no length contraction inside), only the temporal component is continuous (the same time dilation inside as on the outer surface), as discussed here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4428

Comment: @safesphere: Both definitions work. The inside is precisely the Minkowski metric (with inside time rescaled relative to the time at infinity) so  circumference divided by $2\pi$ and spatial distance from the shell to the center are the same. Metric is continuous, but its first derivatives have discontinuities across the shell (so that curvature has $\delta$-like singularities).

Comment: @A.V.S. Here is what I meant. For the radial metric $d\tau^2=A(r)dt^2-B(r)dr^2$,  $A(r)$ is continuous through the infinitely thin shell, but $B(r)$ is not. The radial distance being equal to the reduced circumference doesn't feel right, because over time it doesn't smoothly transition to the Schwarzschild solution where the radial distance and volume inside are zero. Consider we observe this shell from outside for a billion years, so for all practical purposes it is a black hole. Are you saying that by then the volume inside still is $4/3\cdot\pi r^3$ in the remote or internal coordinates?

Comment: @A.V.S. As opposed to this: "*There is zero volume inside the black hole in any Schwarzschild time slice of a Schwarzschild black hole spacetime*" - https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1734

Comment: @A.V.S. Correction: $4/3\cdot\pi r_s^3$ above.

Comment: @safesphere: I (and OP) are considering static spacetimes  formed by a static shell of matter held together against collapse by its own internal stresses, so there is no dynamics here. Also, discontinuity of B(r) could be eliminated if we use different gauge: $ds^2=A(r)dt^2 - dr^2-R(r)^2 d\Omega^2$. And in this gauge, the $R(r)=r$ while inside the shell, so the radius of the shell does not have ambiguity.

Comment: @A.V.S. Thanks, let me ponder this. To clarify, by “transition”, I did not imply dynamics. Consider a set of static shells with the radius increasingly close to $r_s$. For example, the radius of one such static shell (hypothetically) is within the Planck length of $r_s$ or one part in a trillion trillion trillion … Intuitively, physics there should be asymptotically approaching the Schwarzschild solution (at least in some interpretation). For example, time inside is *almost* stopped, as we observe. And so the inner volume should be close to zero, but you insist the volume is unchanged.

Comment: @A.V.S. Above, by “radius close to $r_s$”, I mean the reduced circumference of the outer surface, as measured in remote coordinates. And by “volume inside close to zero”, I mean that the spatial radial distance between the shell and the origin measured by an inside observer is close to zero. In other words, the circumference of the shell is different as measured inside or outside. Also, in your gage, $R(r)$ is still discontinuous at the shell (if infinitely thin). This may remove the ambiguity of the inner radius, but doesn’t prove the volume is intact, e.g. $R(r)\to 0$ if the shell $\to r_s$.

Comment: @safesphere … *physics there should be asymptotically approaching the Schwarzschild solution*. Yes, outside physics! But inside physics can (and will) be vastly different. For instance, ambiguity (and possible zero) for the volume of black hole interior has everything to do with absence of timelike Killing vector field inside. OTOH, for static matter shell KVF inside do exists, so interior volume could be computed with the usual formula for flat-space ball.

Comment: @A.V.S. “*interior volume could be computed with the usual formula for flat-space ball*” - Of course, it is a flat spacetime. This is not a contradiction, if my claim is correct that in your formula $R(r)\to 0$ if the shell $\to r_s$. My apologies for not having a rigorous math to prove this, but I’ve never seen a rigorous disprove either. So I’m looking for a convincing argument to clarify this case. Thanks for your help!

Comment: *Also, in your gage, R(r) is still discontinuous at the shell (if infinitely thin)* No, $R(r)$ is continuous. Israel's junction conditions say that $g_{\theta\theta}$ and $g_{\phi\phi}$ (which are $R^2(r)d\Omega^2$ ) must remain continuous. But $g_{rr}$ may have discontinuities since this component do not contribute to induced metric (because $\partial_r$ is orthogonal to the shell worldvolume). And you seem to be under impression that time dilation must be accompanied by spatial distance compression, but that is wrong, time dilation does not change spatial geometry.

Comment: @A.V.S. Thank you Sir, let me ponder this. To clarify, of course time dilation doesn’t change the spatial geometry directly. However, in a vacuum where the Ricci tensor is zero, the infinitesimal spacetime volume conserves meaning that time dilation equals length contraction. I am not sure how this works through the shell though. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have a non-paywalled alternative.

Comment: @blademan9999 the link “free pdf” is to a copy of the paper on one of authors personal web page.